# How to draw a contiguous line where each segment starts where previous ended

Tags: tikz-pgf

Maybe I'm not thinking about this right, but I would like to draw a line from a set of input data. Each data entry provides a single point in that line. If the line was "static", I'd just do something like:

```
\draw (0,100) -- (50,99) -- (150,80) -- (200,90) -- (250,65);
```

But I would like the y values to come from a data list. I was hoping I could do something like:

```
\draw (0,100) -- (50,99);
\draw -- (150,80);
% etc
```

The idea being that the second `\draw` command uses `(50,99)` as its starting coordinate. That way I could use a `\foreach` or something. But this doesn't work.

Am I missing some clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question completly. Does this look like what you want to achieve?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    
    \draw[line width=2mm, red ] (0,100)
    \foreach \x/\y in {50/99,100/98,150/80,200/90,250/65}
    {-- (\x,\y)};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It surely does! Thanks very much Roland!

Answer (score 1):

Two more options. First one uses `foreach` inside `draw` command and second one uses `plot coordinates` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, line width=2mm] (0,100) foreach \i in {(50,99),(150,80),(200,90),(250,65)}{--\i};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue, line width=2mm] plot coordinates {(0,100) (50,99) (150,80) (200,90) (250,65)};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]